# I am trying to test for a palindrome in C and can't see where I am going wrong

Tags: c

I am trying to make a palindrome checker in C and can't seem to make my code work correctly. I put everything into an array to more easily access input variables by index. Once this was done, I compare the first and last variable and then iterate through until the indexes meet. When I input 121 I get false returned, and this should be true. Any input helps!

```
bool isPalindrome(int x){
    int y = 1;
    int z = 0;
    int p = x;
    while(p != 0)
    {
         p/=10;
        y++;
    }
    int num[y-1];
    p=x;
    int g = y;
    y=0;
    while (p!=0){
        num[y] = p%10;
        p/=10;
        y++;
    }
    y = 0;

    while(y == (g-y) && num[y] != num[g-y-2])
    {
        /*if(num[y] != num[g-y-2])
        {
            return false;
            break;
        }
        else{
            y++;
        }*/
        continue;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You have an unconditional `continue;` before `return true;`. So you'll never return true.

Comment: A good IDE or a compiler with full warnings enabled would tell you that you have unreachable code there.

Comment: You shouldn't check for matching elements in the `while` condition. The algorithm should be to iterate over the indexes. Inside the loop body, check if the two elements are equal. If they aren't, you `return false`. If you get through the loop without finding any mismatches, then you `return true`.

Comment: unreachable code? Im doing this in leetcode so im not trying to download a compiler at the moment.

Comment: I don't use LeetCode, do they have a debugger? That's an essential tool for learning to program.

Comment: An "elite" coder should not be reluctant to install a compiler.

Comment: You figure out a value for `y` and then go `y = 0;`

Comment: @Peazypound1212 I don't use LeetCode, but I submit to some other sites, just for fun. But I never submit a solution until I've solved their test cases locally, and a bunch more that I contrive myself to check out the performance at the limits of the problem's constraints. These sites are not good learning tools, no matter how they pass themselves off.

Comment: What kind of loop would you prefer? I feel like the logic is correct but I just cant get the correct answer.

Comment: The array check is commented-out, has dangerous array indexing, and essentially does nothing or possibly loops forever. This approach of building an array for your digits is really a bit unnecessary. You could instead build a second integer value by constructing the digits in reverse, and compare that it's equal to the original. No array required, much fewer variables required, only one loop required, much less code.

Comment: @paddy Careful. _Scaled down_ example using a single byte: the non-palidrome `118` "fits", but _reversing_ as you described would attempt to build `811`. Not gonna fit. Scale that up to a 4 or 8 byte `int` and the same caution applies...

Comment: You seem to have some fundamental misconceptions about `break`, `continue`, and `return`.  These all effect a transfer of control, so anything that immediately follows them will be unreachable, and hence serve no purpose.  For example, a `return` followed by a `break` is just a `return`.  The `break` can never be executed.  So, delete it.  Similarly, a `continue` followed by `return` is just a `continue`.  The `return` can never be executed.  So, delete it.  You've already managed to confuse yourself with unreachable code.  Get rid of it.  Then it should be easier to find your other mistakes.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Yeah that's a fair point. The original problem seems to be [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number/) which identifies the range as nearly maxing-out a signed 32-bit integer, so a wider type would be required or using additional logic in the loop that ensures overflow will not happen (since overflow would mean it's definitely not a palindrome).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code. The ones that are really breaking it are as follows.

If `x` is zero, you will attempt to allocate a zero sized array for the digits. It's probably best to get that case out of the way first. In fact, any single digit number is a guaranteed palindrome, and no negative number is one (you can't have a minus sign at both ends), so you can put the following at the top of your function

```
    if (x < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (x < 10)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

The next obvious problem is here

```
while(y == (g-y) && num[y] != num[g-y-2])
//    ^^^^^^^^^^==== problem!
```

when you first come to that line, `y` is zero and `g` is "number of digits in x plus 1". That condition is not true. The body of the `while` loop will never be executed. That's why `isPalindrome(121)` returns false.

Most of the body off your loop is commented out but you have

```
    continue;
    return true;
```

That `return` statement is unreachable because the `continue` goes back to the top of the loop (note that, were it not commented out, the `break` after the `return` is also unreachable).

Also, I think your logic is backwards. You need to go through the loop testing pairs until you find two numbers that are not equals and then return false. The return after exiting the loop should then return true.

Your loop should look more like this:

```
int numDigits = ... // Use the actual number of digits not number of digits + 1

// Put stuff in the array etc

int y = 0;
while (y < numDigits - y)
{
    if (num[y] != num[numDigits - y - 1])
    {
        return false;
    }
    y++;
}
return true;
```

Note that compared with you, I have the return conditions reversed.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of good comments there, but with those in mind, unless you were not allowed, you might consider palindrome testing by converting the integer value in question to a string and then performing the testing on the string.  From my experiences, most palindrome tests are on strings (aka character arrays).

With that in mind, following is a refactored version of your code with some input testing functionality added to perform some reasonableness testing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool isPalindrome(int x){
    char check[32];             /* Utilizing a string to store the integer value to simplify testing */
    bool outcome = true;        /* Initialize the bool value to true */
    int end = 0;
    sprintf(check, "%d", x);    /* This puts the integer into the string (the character arrary) */
    end = strlen(check) - 1;    /* Determines the length of the string for testing */

    for (int i = 0; i < (end / 2 + 1); i++)     /* This works from both end into the middle */
    {
        if (i == (end - i))                     /* Met in the middle - therefore can break from the loop */
            break;
        if (check[i] != check[end - i])
        {
            outcome = false;                    /* If an instance of inequality is found, set the bool value to false and leave the loop */
            break;
        }
    }

    return outcome;
}

int main()
{
    bool test;
    int entry;

    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &entry) == 0)
    {
        printf("No entry was provided\n");
        return -1;
    }

    test = isPalindrome(entry);

    if (test)
    {
        printf("The entered number is a palindrome\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The entered number is not a palindrome\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully the comments shed light on what is happening within the test function, but basically a bool variable is defined and initially set to "true", the integer to be tested is outputted to a character array, and then working from both ends of the character array to the middle, equality checks are made to see if each pair of characters (digits) are equal.  If any check fails then the bool variable is set to false and the testing loop is exited.

Trying this out with various values produced the following output.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Palindrome/bin/Release$ ./Palindrome 
Please enter a number: 121
The entered number is a palindrome
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Palindrome/bin/Release$ ./Palindrome 
Please enter a number: 122
The entered number is not a palindrome
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Palindrome/bin/Release$ ./Palindrome 
Please enter a number: 1221
The entered number is a palindrome
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Palindrome/bin/Release$ ./Palindrome 
Please enter a number: 12321
The entered number is a palindrome
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Palindrome/bin/Release$ ./Palindrome 
Please enter a number: 12312
The entered number is not a palindrome
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Palindrome/bin/Release$ ./Palindrome 
Please enter a number: 12422421
The entered number is a palindrome
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Palindrome/bin/Release$ ./Palindrome 
Please enter a number: 1235321
The entered number is a palindrome
```

So again, since most palindrome tests are over strings or word sets, you might want to try this approach if allowed.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, hope-it-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc.